# Using javascript and php in html. mass confusion

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to make a php document that will work on a mobile device.  We have some javascript to display buttons at the top of the app for navigation.  My php document is suppose to show up right below the buttons.  It should be a fairly simple page but I am struggling pretty bad.  I am trying to simply call a function that sets a variable.  I want to use this variable to display the amount of money the person using the app has.  I'm running into problems with the functions and variables. I've been told html can't use varaibles or functions, so I need to break into php and use "echo functionName(); so: declare function, call function to set variable, display variable on the page inside of a div.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<?php

?>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //int $availableBal;
    //int $currentHoldings;
    function int getBalance();
    {

        int $availableBal = 500;
        //alert("you have " + $availableBal + " dollars to spend");
        return $availableBal;
    }

    function void getHoldings()
    {
        int $MSFT_Shares = 5;
        int $MFST_Price= 100;
        int $currentHoldings = $MSFT_Shares * $MSFT_Price;
        return $currentHoldings;
    }
    </script>   
    <style>
html {text-align:center}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="totalMoney" align="center" style= "border:1px solid grey">         
            You have a current balance of: $ <?php 'echo getBalance();' ?> 
            <br>
            <!--The total worth of your current stocks is: $ <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(getHoldings();)</script> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Javascript at all...seems like a mix of Java and PHP, wth?

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs... also noticed that you have a semi-colon (;) after your `getBalance()` function, which probably wouldn't be helping anything.

Comment: Right, also what about `<?php 'echo getBalance();' ?>`? @Terak I suggest you start from _zero_ and go _step by step_. Don't rush into PHP and JS, learn the basics first...

Comment: PHP code doesn't mix with JS like that. You can't call JS functions from PHP. On a side note, your php code shouldn't be in single-quotes. `<?php echo getBalance();?>`

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed the two languages together. Javascript is a client side application, where PHP is server sided.

All this can be achieved with both, I've mocked up one working for you in javascript, with a bit of jquery for display.
http://jsfiddle.net/Nj3ce/

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
    <script text="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           //on document load this function will be fired
           //automatically runs getHoldings();
           var holdings = getHoldings();
            $('#totalMoney span').text(holdings);
        });

        function getBalance(){
            var availableBal = 500;
            return availableBal;
        }

        function getHoldings(){
            var MFST_Shares = 5;
            var MFST_Price = 100;
            var currentHoldings = MFST_Shares * MFST_Price;
            return currentHoldings;
        }​
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {text-align:center}​
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="totalMoney" align="center" style= "border:1px solid grey">         
            You have a current balance of: $<span></span>
            <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Thanks all.  Its going to take a little while to walk through this and make sure I know whats going on.  I'm needing to use php because I have to contact the server to get the information about the total spending money and value of owned stocks (holdings). We're making a stock market simulator.  These are just test functions. Sorry that my code was so jumbled.  I was trying any option I could think of.  is Jquery (or the link you left me) a place where i can test my code? i have to upload it to gethub and test from our site.  but everyone sees all changes. +site updates once ever 15 mins.

Comment: Jsfiddle is for clientside. So you can place your html, css, javscript, jquery etc and see it execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to declare functions separate in each language in this case. All you want to do there can be done solely with php. And for cleanness, take the `<!DOCTYPE>` and move above the php. also, include a separate file with all the code and let the html with less css/javascript/php

Comment: so does php work like C? in the sense that you need to have separate files? one for functions and one for the driver?

Comment: ideally yes, separating it has advantages

Comment: It's not obligatory. It's common practice to have the most part in separate files. It will help with security issues, readability and organization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare datatypes in javascript. (i.e. `function int`, `int $availableBal`). This can all be done in PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<?php
    // Should really put this in an external file
    function getBalance()
    {
        $iAvailableBal = 500;
        return $iAvailableBal;
    }

    function getHoldings()
    {
        $iMSFTShares = 5;
        $iMSFTPrice = 100;
        $iCurrentHoldings = $iMSFTShares * $iMSFTPrice;
        return $iCurrentHoldings;
    }
?>
<style type="text/css">
/* Should really put this in an external file */
html {text-align:center}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="totalMoney" align="center" style= "border:1px solid grey">         
            You have a current balance of: $ <?php echo getBalance(); ?> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: terakraines@yahoo.com if anybody is able to contact me through Yahoo Instant Messenger.